# Cannot print my first element in a cpp array

Tags: c++

I am programming in cpp to print the first element of my array but not showing in the output. But its showing the right answer in other elements.
Please checkout!!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a[4]={1011};
    int b[4]={0011};
    cout<<a[0]<<endl;
    cout<<b[0]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `int a[4]={1,0,1,1};` and `int b[4]={0,0,1,1};`

Comment: *"right answer in other elements"* - that's highly unlikely.

Comment: @LogicStuff: complete hogwash indeed, especially given that 0011 is an octal literal!

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `int a[4]={1,0,1,1};` etc. Better still, let the compiler compute the size: `int a[] = {1,0,1,1};` is preferred.

Currently you are setting `a[0]` to `1011` and C++ sets the other 3 elements to zero.

`b[0]` is more interesting. It is actually equal to 9. The leading `0` in `0011` denotes an *octal literal*, so you're setting `b[0]` to Octal 11, which, in base 10, is 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to intialize an array with `{}` brackets, you have to **separate them with commas**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[4] = {1,0,1,1};
    int b[4] = {0,0,1,1};
    cout << a[0] << endl;
    cout << b[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Working piece of code: http://ideone.com/7SX0zG